# Subclassing pandas DataFrame for an ETL

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a small ETL, which loads data from CSVs, cleans each table a bit, and then loads everything into a PostgreSQL database. I was planning to use pandas for its built-in capabilities, but am wondering whether to subclass DataFrame or whether to just do everything functionally.

The subclassed DataFrame code is pasted below. For maintainability by non-developers, I have a small YAML file with information about each table and column type.

```
import pandas
import numpy
import yaml
from os import path

CFG = yaml.load(open('config.yaml', 'r'))

class ETLDataTable(pandas.DataFrame):
    _metadata = ['table_name', 'file_name', 'columns', 'notes']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return ETLDataTable

    def __init__(self, table_name):
        # Name of the database table
        self.table_name = CFG[table_name]['table']
        # Name of the CSV file
        self.file_name = CFG[table_name]['file']
        # Whether file has note fields
        self.notes = CFG[table_name]['notes']

        #Data Types to feed into read_csv
        try:
            self.columns = CFG[table_name]['columns']
        except:
            pass

        _ = path.join(path.abspath(path.pardir), self.file_name)
        super().__init__(pandas.read_csv(_))

    def load_df(self, root_path, **kwargs):
    """Read the csv associated with the table name,
    then import as a pandas DataFrame
    """
        _ = path.join(path.abspath(path.pardir), self.file_name)
        pandas.read_csv(csv_path, 
                        na_values = ['00000000', ' ', ''],
                        encoding="latin1",
                        dtype="object",
                        **kwargs)
```

Going forward I was planning to add in some methods that are needed by every table: fixing bad dates, stripping empty strings, etc. Is this approach going to be more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: You can make a datatype Class, but I would not have it subclass a `DataFrame`. Just have a `data` property

Comment: To make sure I understand what you're saying: I'd have one attribute of the class be a dataframe?

Comment: Does this use [PyYaml](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) or another yaml library?

Comment: @Dannnno PyYaml, if I remember correctly. Why do you ask?

Comment: @RebeccaAckerman to make sure we have the appropriate context; it would mostly matter if it was a custom yaml library you implemented yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the parsing and analysis of my tests, I did something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

class MyTest:

    def __init__(self, settings: dict, root_dir: Path):
        self.table_name = settings['table']
        self.file_name = settings['file']
        ...
        self.columns = settings.get('columns', None)

        filename = root_dir / self.file_name
        data = read_data(filename, columns=self.columns)
        self._data = fix_data(data)

    def summary_x(self):
        ...
        return None

    def get_data_between(self, date1, date2):
        # optionally parsing the dates
        return self._data[self._data['data'].between(date1, date2)]

    ...

def read_data(filename, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        na_values=['00000000', ' ', ''],
        encoding="latin1",
        dtype="object",
        **kwargs,
    )

def fix_data(data: pd.DataFrame, date_cols=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    if date_cols:
        date_cols = (date_cols,) if isinstance(date_cols, str) else date_cols
        data[date_cols] = [fix_dates(data[col]) for col in date_cols]
    ...
    return data

def fix_dates(data: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    #optionally a column
    pass

def remove_empty_strings(data):
    pass
```

Once I was at the stage where I had multiple types of tests, I made a generic type, and subclassed this. But I see little value in subclassing `pandas.Dataframe`, because then you also have to take care not to accidentally overwrite any of it's methods and attributes